# Access default implementation of CustomStringConvertible in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

I want to extend the default behaviour of the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol in my `class`, by adding some extra output.

For example, say you have this `class` in a project called Bar:

```
class Baz {
   let x = 42
}
let b = Baz()
```

When doing a `po(b)`, the output will be `Bar.Baz`

I want to display some extra stuff, such as the value of `x`, without having to type again Bar.Baz

Is this possible?

Comment: Please show us an example of what you want to happen when you print a custom class.

Comment: The protocol doesn't have a default implementation, each class/struct must implement it's own version

Comment: @AlexPopov I just edited the question

Comment: Good question, but there are still no direct answer. Can it be reopened somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why most of the classes you use have a default implementation of `CustomStringConvertible` is because `NSObject` (the superclass of all Obj-C classes) implements it.

If you have defined your own Swift base class, you must first declare that it conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and then implement it, e.g.

```
class Dog: CustomStringConvertible {
  // some code and stuff here
  var name = "Bobby"

  // conform to CustomStringConvertible
  var description: String {
    return "\(NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)) \(name)"
  }
}

print(Dog()) // outputs: "__lldb_expr_70.Dog Bobby" in Playground
```

A class that does not conform to `CustomStringConvertible` merely prints the class name.

Comment: My class doesn't inherit from NSObject.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. Added solution to answer.